# Use a PHP file pointer resource in C extension

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I started developing my own little extension for PHP. But I'm struggling now with the resource types.

Basically I like to use a file pointer passed as parameter to my own function. So let's say the following PHP code is the end result:

```
<?php

$fp = fopen('file.txt', 'w');

my_ext_function($fp);
```

Now I like to play around with this file pointer in C back in my extension:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(my_ext_function)
{
        zval *res;
        php_stream *stream;

        char ch;

        if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS(), "r", &res) == FAILURE) {
                RETURN_FALSE;
        }

        PHP_STREAM_TO_ZVAL(stream, res); // Not sure about that

        // Do some crazy stuff here like it would be a native file pointer from C
        while( ( ch = fgetc(res) ) != EOF )
            php_printf("%c", res);

        RETURN_TRUE;
}
```

My extension function is based on the [`fread` function of PHP itself](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/cf50748f2ba16cef1d2931c0d8afc717dea8eab7/ext/standard/file.c#L1763).

So how can I achieve this? Basically the question is: how can cast the `php_stream` pointer to a `FILE` pointer?

**BACKTRACE**

```
#0  0x000000010081b330 in zend_parse_va_args (num_args=1, type_spec=0x7fff5fbfec88 "@9\321\002\001", va=0x7fff5fbfec10, flags=0, tsrm_ls=0x102cdef07) at Zend/zend_API.c:790
#1  0x000000010081bc67 in zend_parse_parameters (num_args=1, tsrm_ls=0x102cdef07, type_spec=0x7fff5fbfec88 "@9\321\002\001") at Zend/zend_API.c:924
#2  0x0000000102cdeb2a in zif_my_ext_function (ht=1, return_value=0x102cd2d38, return_value_ptr=0x102c9e168, this_ptr=0x0, return_value_used=0, tsrm_ls=0x102d13940) at hello.c:65
#3  0x00000001008cacd5 in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (execute_data=0x102c9e1c0, tsrm_ls=0x102d13940) at Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:558
#4  0x0000000100882252 in ZEND_DO_FCALL_SPEC_CONST_HANDLER (execute_data=0x102c9e1c0, tsrm_ls=0x102d13940) at Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:2595
#5  0x0000000100869f28 in execute_ex (execute_data=0x102c9e1c0, tsrm_ls=0x102d13940) at Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:363
#6  0x000000010086a060 in zend_execute (op_array=0x102cd39f0, tsrm_ls=0x102d13940) at Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:388
#7  0x00000001007fde27 in zend_eval_stringl (str=0x102d138a0 "$fp = fopen(\"test.txt\", \"r\"); my_ext_function($fp);", str_len=41, retval_ptr=0x0,
    string_name=0x100dbd1d6 "Command line code", tsrm_ls=0x102d13940) at Zend/zend_execute_API.c:1077
#8  0x00000001007fe627 in zend_eval_stringl_ex (str=0x102d138a0 "$fp = fopen(\"test.txt\", \"r\"); my_ext_function($fp);", str_len=41, retval_ptr=0x0,
    string_name=0x100dbd1d6 "Command line code", handle_exceptions=1, tsrm_ls=0x102d13940) at Zend/zend_execute_API.c:1124
#9  0x00000001007fe6ff in zend_eval_string_ex (str=0x102d138a0 "$fp = fopen(\"test.txt\", \"r\"); my_ext_function($fp);", retval_ptr=0x0, string_name=0x100dbd1d6 "Command line code",
    handle_exceptions=1, tsrm_ls=0x102d13940) at Zend/zend_execute_API.c:1135
#10 0x00000001008f96ab in do_cli (argc=3, argv=0x102d13840, tsrm_ls=0x102d13940) at sapi/cli/php_cli.c:1034
#11 0x00000001008f8172 in main (argc=3, argv=0x102d13840) at sapi/cli/php_cli.c:1378
```

Comment: My bet is `stream->stdiocast` (a `FILE*`), but I haven't tried it. Could you try and see if it works?

Comment: At least it compiles now but I get an `Internal Server Error` now if I call the `my_ext_function($fp)`. Can I somewhere see the runtime errors of the extension?

Comment: I'd check the error logs of PHP and the web server. Also, if you're on Mac/Linux and `gdb` is available, try `sudo gdb -ex run --args php -a`, then type `$fp = fopen('file.txt', 'w'); my_ext_function($fp);` and hit enter. If it crashes, you should get an error message and you can use `bt` to get a stack trace to the position where it crashes (doesn't mean the code there is *responsible* for the crash).

Comment: I installed `gdb` but when I enter the code after `php >` nothing happens. I can even put invalid PHP code like `xyz;` and nothing happens. Just another `php >` if I hit enter.

Comment: If you actually put a semicolon at the end and it behaves like this, then that sounds seriously broken o.0

Comment: Okay added backtrace in my question. I recompiled PHP with debug flag and used `sudo gdb -ex run --args /usr/local/php-5.6.7-debug/bin/php -r '...'` and now I get `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000010081b330 in zend_parse_va_args (num_args=1, type_spec=0x7fff5fbfec88 "@9\321\002\001", va=0x7fff5fbfec10, flags=0, tsrm_ls=0x102cdef07) at Zend/zend_API.c:790
790      zend_function *active_function = EG(current_execute_data)->function_state.function;`

Comment: What API are you developing against? 5.x or 7?

Comment: Also, why don't you simply use [`php_stream_read()`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/main/php_streams.h#305)?

Comment: Against 5.x well I actually need to pass a file pointer to a C function.

Comment: Replace `ZEND_NUM_ARGS()` with `ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC` (no comma) - if you're not working with PHP 7, you shouldn't use the PHP 7 `fread` function as guideline. [Here's the PHP 5 one](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-5.6.10/ext/standard/file.c#L1754).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PHP_STREAM_TO_ZVAL` can't be used directly because it's declared inside the implementation of `ext/standard/file.c`; you need to use this instead:

```
php_stream_from_zval(stream, &res);
```

You can cast the stream to what you need using [`php_stream_cast()`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/main/php_streams.h#482):

```
{
    FILE *f;

    if (FAILURE == php_stream_cast(stream, PHP_STREAM_AS_STDIO, (void**)&f, REPORT_ERRORS))   {
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }
    /* do what you want with f */
}
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much :-). But I need first `php_stream_from_zval(stream, &res);` because now it tells me: that I can not implicit declare `PHP_STREAM_TO_ZVAL`

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER No problem! I'm not sure how this affects the stream, though; should be fine if you don't read from the file outside of the extension, though :)

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER Right, I didn't check where that macro was declared :) updated my answer.

Comment: Perfect. Just because I'm interested in... where did you find the solution? Are your skills that strong in PHP extension development or did you found the solution somewhere in the internet to my question?

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER A bit of both; I'm a core developer and I use [this part](http://lxr.php.net) of the internet to find answers pertaining to these sorts of questions :)